# Automatically generating table entries in Ruby on Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I've got a table called "Customers". The table can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XF3W.png). "description" is string while "fruit" is integer. "fruit" will not be displayed to a user when filling in the table. Instead, I want ruby to automatically assign the value "0" to the "fruit" column if the corresponding answer for "description" is "yes". So if a user selects yes, the table shall automatically generate a 0 in the fruit column and if the user selects no, it shall automatically generate a 1 in the column... Any ideas?? Thank you in advance!!

Comment: What have you tried so far?  There are a few ways to approach this.  And, if they are always locked, do you need two columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add before_save filter in User Model

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :assign_fruit

  private
  def assign_fruit
    self.fruits = (self.description == "yes" ? 1 : 0 )
  end
end
```

Comment: If I wanted to do it the other way around... if i wanted to turn a "1" into a "yes".. I tried this:
`def assign_test
    self.test = (self.description == "1" ? "yes" : "no" )
  end`

Now, whether i put in a 1 or a 0 or whatever else, it returns a "no" in the table... can you help?

Comment: try self.description == 1 ? "yes" : "no"

Answer (score 1):

your question is kind of vague - please provide more details.

How does the user input yes/no?

Is it by submitting a form to update or create? 
If so you could write something like this in the action

```
if params[:answer]
  instance.update_attribute(fruit, true)
end
```

If you are trying to accomplish this in a show page (let's say by clicking a checkbox)

you could achieve this with jQuery
i.e.

```
$('.checkbox_selector/.select_box_selector').on('change', function() {
  // ajax the boolean 
});
```

I will need more information to respond with a less generic answer
anyway hope this helps

i would also recommend setting fruit as a boolean and not an integer.